# sql server Xquery nodes value performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a table with 25,000 rows. Table Audit (Id int identity(1,1), AdditionalInfo xml)
The sample data in AdditionalInfo column for a row looks like below

```
<Audit version="1">
  <Context name="Event">
    <Action name="OrganizationEventReceived">
      <Input>
        <Source type="SourceOrganizationId">77d2678b-ea4a-43ad-816b-c63edf206b08</Source>
        <Target type="TargetOrganizationId">b98fd3ae-dbcb-4826-9d92-7e445ad61273,b98fd3ae-dbcb-4826-9d92-7e445ad61273,b98fd3ae-dbcb-4826-9d92-7e445ad61273</Target>
      </Input>
    </Action>
  </Context>
</Audit>
```

I like to shred  the xml and collect the data in output dataset with following query.

```
SELECT   Id,
         p.value('(@name)[1]', 'nvarchar (100)') AS TargetAction, 
         p.value('(Input/Source/text())[1]', 'nvarchar (500)') AS Source, 
         p.value('(Input/Target/text())[1]', 'nvarchar (max)') AS Target
FROM dbo.Audit  CROSS APPLY AdditionalInfo.nodes('/Audit/Context/Action') AS AdditionalInfo(p)
```

The performance of the query is bad. It is taking 15 seconds to give the result set for just 25,000 rows. Is there a better way of doing it. I even tried putting primary and secondary xml indexes on AdditionalInfo column. Please help and let me know, to use better sql server xquery techniques.

Thanks,

Comment: How many `Action` elements do you have per row on average?

Comment: Also, how far your server and your client machine are located from one another? And what quality the network between them is? I mean, I tried the same test on my 2yo laptop and it returned 25000 rows in 1 second. Or maybe you have much more columns in your table, it can make somewhat of a difference...

Answer (score 0):

Great question.

My recent task requires to parse about 35'000 XML documents, valid document being ~20kB.

More and larger xml files tend to exponentially fill the memory:

- 100 documents: 0:33
- 1000 documents: 25:00 ‍

Try to distribute your work:

- Variable `target` stores unstructured data, which eats most of computing power due to the data type and different length in values
- depth of nodes in `CROSS APPLY` matters: avoid triple nodes in `nodes()`, consider two nodes and recursion (see below on split)
- batch mode: process several documents at time, `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`
- loop a list of documents, `FOR`;
- parse using local variables, such as `DECLARE @xml_doc XML; SET @xml_doc = SELECT xmldata FROM xmlsource WHERE id=1;`
- avoid exporting xml node content, only write result values
- parse all elements separately: saving order of elements using function `ROW_NUMBER()`, then `LEFT JOIN` all parts to xml documents list using some identifier, such as `xml_id`